# I have a randomly order list in each row that I want to convert to a boolean column, using the contents as the column name in R

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a randomly ordered list in each row of my dataframe that I want to convert to a boolean column, using the contents of the list element as the column name in R.

Sample data from the list:

```
[[9675]]
[1] "Jazz"       "Music"
[[9676]]
[1] "Modern"         "Opera"    "Music" 
[[9677]]
[1] "Rock"      "Music"     
[[9678]]
[1] "HMetal"       "Rock"     "Music"
```

I would like the result to be something like:

```
      Genre.Music Genre.Modern Genre.Jazz Genre.Classical Genre.Opera Genre.Rock Genre.HMetal 
[[9675]]   1           0             1          0               0           0          0
[[9676]]   1           1             0          0               1           0          0            
[[9677]]   1           0             0          0               0           1          0                                                         1                                                     
[[9678]]   1           0             0          0               0           1          1
```

I am hoping that I will be able to create each column on-the-fly as each record is read, because I have about 200 genres in total.

Is there any way in R that I can use the contents of a list item as the key of the column? I can certainly sort the lists in advance if that helps in the column-creation process.

I'm going to be using the end result in a statistical analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
lst <- list(
  A = letters[1:2],
  B = letters[2:4]
)
lst
# $A
# [1] "a" "b"
# 
# $B
# [1] "b" "c" "d"
library(reshape2)
(df <- recast(lst, L1~value))
#   L1    a b    c    d
# 1  A    a b <NA> <NA>
# 2  B <NA> b    c    d
cbind(df[1], (!is.na(df[-1])) +0L)
#   L1 a b c d
# 1  A 1 1 0 0
# 2  B 0 1 1 1
```